# how to get hostname from Javascript, so that user cannot spoof it?

Tags: javascript

Though we can get the hostname from the javascript by using `window.location.hostname` but the other user can download the js and pass it as constant valid hostname, I'm working on something for which I need to know where the script is hosted and the user of that js cannot spoof it.

One more solution which i thought of is using `request.headers.origin` but that also can be spoofed.

Is there any such solution by which I can get the hostname where the js is hosted so that I can restrict unauthorized use of js hosting.

I tried googling but couldn't find any solution. The solution which most people suggest is to obfuscate the js code after passing it from js only.

Can we do better?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Everything that happens in the browser is entirely under the control of the user.

If you don't trust the user, then you can't trust any information you get from the browser.

You should find a source for the information that doesn't depend so heavily on the browser (e.g. generating the information server side and then associating it with information from the browser via the use of a session).

Comment: so there isn't any secure way to get the host, where my js is hosted ?  btw thanks for answering.